# How to get database value in AJAX Script using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Below i have mentioned AJAX script, I wanted to append id from database for each photo when I  upload.But when using "**var m='_'+x;**" in the below script it doesnt get the database id for the record(WHen i print it,It appears blank).So how to retrieve database id for a row and append in AJAX script?The photo gets uploaded and stores in the mentioned folder with the id.But in that page while i check page source it shows .The Id doesnt get loaded in middle.

```
$(function(){
    var btnUpload=$('#me');
    var mestatus=$('#mestatus');
    var files=$('#files');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'uploadPhoto.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext)
        {
             if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                // extension is not allowed 
                mestatus.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            mestatus.html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" height="16" width="16" align="left">');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
        // alert(response)
            //On completion clear the status
            mestatus.text('');
            //On completion clear the status
            files.html('');
            //Add uploaded file to list
            if(response==="success")
            {
                var x=file;

                  var m='<?=$data44[id]?>_'+x;


                document.getElementById('img_name').value=x;
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="photo/demophoto_'+m+'" alt="" height="110px" width="95px" /><br />').addClass('success');
            } else{
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Uploadphoto.php**

```
include_once("db.php");

$sel="select usnno from usn where id='$_SESSION[lgkey]'";

$qry=mysql_query($sel) or die(mysql_error());

$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

 $sel44=mysql_query("select * from reg_form where usn='$row[usnno]' ");

                       $data44=mysql_fetch_array($sel44);

$uploaddir = './photo/'; 

$file = $uploaddir ."demophoto_".$data44['id'].'_'.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

$file_name= "demophoto_".$data44['id'].'_'.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']; 



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 

  echo "success";

} else {

    echo "error";

}
```

Comment: Allen plz. Y U NO show uploadPhoto.php code?

Comment: I have added uploadphoto.php

Comment: Maybe you should start by actually storing the image in the database in some way.

Comment: The photo gets uploaded and and stores in specified folder with the id but in the front end after uplading it doesnt load the id in that AJAX script when i press Update in php it stores the path without the id ,so it wont get loaded properly ..

Comment: Should not be var m='<?=$data44['id']?>_'+x; instead of var m='<?=$data44[id]?>_'+x; ? So adding (') between the id ?

Comment: Yeah i tried that way also still its not working ..

Comment: You can try doing: <? var_dump($data44); ?> and see what is in your sever response. But I would say it is definitely "id" instead of id.

Comment: Try with double "id". so it would be: var m='<?=$data44["id"]?>_'+x

Comment: try this var m="<?=$data44['id']?>_"+x; instead of var m='<?=$data44[id]?>_'+x;

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code from:

`var m='<?=$data44[id]?>_'+x;`

to the following:

`var m='<?=$data44["id"]?>_'+x;`

Just add double quotation marks between the "id".

Comment: still its not loading the id.This is what i get <img src="photo/demophoto__profile.png" alt="" height="110px" width="95px">.

Comment: Can you do: <? var_dump($data44); ?>

Comment: Allan if you want to use the response from the server, please instead of ' echo "success";' do echo $data44['id']; and then use the javascript 'response' variable. Try doing console.log(response) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Ttry this
`var m="<?php echo $data44['id']; ?>_"+x;` or `var m='<?php echo $data44[id]; ?>_'+x;`
 instead of `var m='<?=$data44[id]?>_'+x;`